# Using PyCall inside Julia module

Tags: python, julia

I am trying to use the Python module `camb` which contains the function `CAMBparams` in Julia via `PyCall`. The following minimal example code works in a Jupyter notebook:

```
using PyCall
camb=pyimport("camb")

function test()
   pars = camb.CAMBparams()
end 

test()
```

I try to do the same thing inside my module `my_module` like so:

```
module my_module

export test

using PyCall
camb=pyimport("camb")

function test()
   pars = camb.CAMBparams()
end 

end #end of module
```

OK, now inside my Jupyter notebook, which is in the same folder where my module script is saved, I do:

```
using my_module
test()
```

and I get the error: `ArgumentError: ref of NULL PyObject`. I attempted what is suggested here: https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl#using-pycall-from-julia-modules, but that did not fix my problem.